# How to make a component loads above header on reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to make a component ( banner ) pop up above my header when the page is done loading.

I've got some help from our fantastic community but this code make the header as the whole loads and I cannot find a way to make it pop above my header component nor a way to implement it.

I would like some help from our community. Here is the code that make the whole header pops after two seconds :

```
class Banner extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
          showHeader: false
       }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       setTimeout(() => this.setState({showHeader: true}), 2000);
    }

      render() {
       return (
         this.state.showHeader && <div className="test">test</div>
       );
     }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Banner/>, document.getElementById('banner'))
```

and html

```
<style>
.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.test2{
   width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='banner'></div>
<div id='header'></div>
```

How to make a banner that will load above the header after the page fully loads ?

Comment: `<div/>` is not a self-closing tag, you have to close it this way : `<div></div>`. currently I guess that your header is contained inside the banner (and also the rest of the page, for that matter)

Comment: @JeremyThille Mistake corrected Any tip how to achieve this ?

Comment: But is it working now? Because it should. The banner is above the header.

Comment: No, Didn't changed a thing

Comment: where is the css for the header?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I haven't inclueded it.... I am very confused right now and need some guidance

Comment: Thats what I was getting at. You left out a very important piece of information. My guess is that the styles of your header are something like `position: absolute;` where the header is over the banner. but you dont see the banner because its under the header.

Comment: @JohnRuddell okay let me try this

Comment: @JohnRuddell How can I create a div just below the yellow block ?

Comment: Its very hard for me to debug an issue without a way to actually debug it. Can you create a js fiddle replicating your issue?

Comment: @JohnRuddell sure ! jsfiddle here =>  https://jsfiddle.net/455s7wsk/ basically I wanted the yellow block to be to banner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145301/discussion-between-john-ruddell-and-gabriel-d).

Answer (score 0):

inside your render you need to use curly braces to clarify what should be rendered and what shouldn't be.. here is an example

```
return (
    <div>
       {this.state.showHeader ? <div className="test">test</div> : null }
       <div className="test2">test2</div>
    </div>
);
```

instead of this

```
return (
    this.state.showHeader && <div className="test">test</div>,
    <div className="test2">test2</div>
);
```

then you can add additional things like animations to make one item slide down from the top revealing the banner.

```
return (
    <div>
        {this.state.showHeader ? <div className="test">test</div> : null }
        <div className={`test2${this.state.showHeader ? ' animate' : ''}`}>test2</div>
    </div>
);
```

your css would be something like..

```
.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.test2{
   width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  top: 0;
}
.animate {
  top: 50px;
}
```

[SAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/455s7wsk/4/)